# MaskedTextBox does not showing starting characters

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0, maskedtextbox

### I have C# DotNet Windows Application form

[image]

### in my application have two MaskedTextBox and they are showing different values.

**Property of Mask 1**

- FONT : Microsoft Sans Serif Regular size 16pt
- RIGHT TO LEFT : NO
- TEXT ALIGN : LEFT
- MASK : >&&&&&&&&&
- WIDTH : 100
- HEIGHT : 31
- TEXT : ASHISH PATIDAR

**Property of Mask 2**

- FONT : Microsoft Sans Serif Regular size 16pt
- RIGHT TO LEFT : NO
- TEXT ALIGN : LEFT
- MASK :
- WIDTH : 100
- HEIGHT : 31
- TEXT : ASHISH PATIDAR

**1st MaskedTextBox have Mask and 2nd have not Mask, rest property are same.**

- Case 1 
  when set the mask and value are shown like "HISH_PAT" as MASK 1 text box.(as show in image).
- Case 2 
  when does not set the mask and value are shown like "ASHISH P" as MASK 2 text box (as show in image).

**I want to show value like "ASHISH P" as MASK 2 text box (as show in image). 
When the Mask is SET, but I do not want to change width of MaskedTextBox.**

How to resolve this ?

Comment: This is a tough question to understand.  Why does the width matter?  Is the underscore "_" character the issue?  The length of the string?

Comment: @LarsTech
The width is matter for my application form, because there is no enough space for this control. The underscore `"_"`  character is not the issue. I have assign the mask so that it show like underscore `"_"` . My issue is MASK 1 hide the starting character of given string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just played around bit with the `MaskedTextBox` properties and it looks to be default behaviour of the control and co-related with `Width`. So when the length of the text to be displayed exceeds proportionate to the width of the control, the text towards end is shown.

I managed to make use of the `maskedTextBox.Select` property manually move the to the 1st character of with the below code line;

```
maskedTextBox1.Select(0, 1);
```

The above line selects the first character of the control, which enables to show the start of the entered text/ selection. The code should be called from the `maskedTextBox1.Leave` event. If your app displays some data at the start of the application/ screen then the same would have to be called from the `Form.Load` event as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this, only copy and paste, it works perfect to me...change you mtb label actually...

```
private void maskedTextBox_MaskInputRejected(object sender, MaskInputRejectedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Text = "Error: " +
    e.RejectionHint.ToString() +
    "; position: " +
    e.Position.ToString();
    }
```